# Delphi timer - not so simple

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am using Delphi 2009 on Windows 10.

I have a simple timer (`JvTimer`, but same problem with `TTimer`) with its `Interval` set to 1000ms in the Object Inspector.  It is showing a countdown in a label.

I have done this many times, but for some reason it isn't working this time. It seems to randomly skip 9, 7, 5, etc.

I have changed the label, timer, interval but still the same - debugging gives the correct steps, but as soon as I run it outside of the debugger, I get the problem.

```
var
  timeout: integer;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if timeout1 < 1 then
  begin
    jvTimer1.Enabled := False; 
    if WindowState = wsNormal then
      WindowState := wsMinimized;
  end
  else
  begin
    Dec(timeout1);
    LabeledEdit5.Text := IntToStr(timeout1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can't we have a MCVE

Comment: Labeled5.update might help you. Sounds like other things are going on and there isn't time to repaint the control.

Comment: Thanks - but I have already tried this and also refreshing the form. No difference. The peculiar thing is that if I create a new project with just a timer,button and label - it works OK. The original prog has nothing in it that causes any events whilst this ttimer is counting down. Also, the numbers are counting down at a higher rate (approx 500ms- i.e. 7-5-3 goes at 1 sec intervals), although the numbers change at the correct rate. Very peculiar!!

Comment: I'm testing this in debug mode - if I put break points in every function and procedure apart from the timer event, none of them are tripped, so I presume it cant be anything to do with any other sections

Comment: If I run without debugging - still the same problem.

Comment: Do you maybe create the timers dynamically at run time? If so, this function might be called multiple times, so that there are multiple instances of the timer active at the same time.

Comment: Or you might have different timer components on the form using the same Timer1Timer event handler. As @DavidHeffernan has said, please provide a minimal but complete sample.

Answer (score 1):

Timers are not very precise. Do not count time by counting how many times the timer event was executed.

Instead: Remember the current TDateTime in a variable when starting the timer, then inside the timer event, calculate the time passed since starting the timer by comparing the current time with that remembered start time.

Comment: Surely a one second timer should not cause problems! As far as I am aware, there are no other events happening in the application at the same time.

Comment: @user If you won't show us your code, how can we help. Why oh why can't we have a MCVE? Do you want help or not?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Dave,
I hacked it all to provide an MCVE and I found the problem.
Somehow this error had crept in!!
I had created the mainform twice. This must have caused the timer problem.
Chris

```
program mail2p;    
uses
  madExcept,
  madLinkDisAsm,
  madListHardware,
  madListProcesses,
  madListModules,
  Forms,
  mail2 in 'mail2.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
 // Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Also change the timeout variable from a global variable to a member field of the form class, so that different instances of the form do not use the same variable.